# View number of added/deleted lines from VSCode GUI

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am aware that `git diff --stat` can be used to view the number of added and deleted lines between a commit and an unstaged change, like so:

```
 src/core.cpp | 31 +++++++++++++++++++++++++------
 1 file changed, 25 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)
```

But it is cumbersome to open a terminal and minimize it every time I want to view these metrics. Is there an easy way to view these in the editor, whether built inside VSCode itself or provided by an extension?

Comment: VSCode has an integrated terminal. Press Ctrl + \` to open it.

Comment: @Kraigolas that is what I currently use but I want to keep that window minimized so I get the full vertical space of the editor. It's a productivity thing.